# REST API Routes Translation

Tags: .net, rest

In a VB.net REST project,  we have routes in this format

```
<Route("~/Apiv2/myfunction")>
<HttpGet>
Public Function MyFunction() As HttpResponseMessage
'code
end function
```

Suppose if we decide to change the route to `"~/api/v2/myfunction"`, is there a way to provide a translation from the old route to the new route so that existing clients continue to work without updating the routes in client code?

Comment: you could use rewriting....

Comment: @DanielA.White can you please point me to some more information on this somewhere?  I think I can do it in haproxy, right?